# Syntax error when declaring a parameter called 'this'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, this

```
typedef struct {
    index_tree_node node;
    uint32_t number;
    lzma_vli block_number_base;
    index_tree groups;
    lzma_vli record_count;
    lzma_vli index_list_size;
    lzma_stream_flags stream_flags;
    lzma_vli stream_padding;
} index_stream;
```

Below is the function:

```
static void
index_cat_helper(const index_cat_info *info, index_stream *this)   //problem line
{
    index_stream *left = (index_stream *)(this->node.left);
    index_stream *right = (index_stream *)(this->node.right);

    if (left != NULL)
        index_cat_helper(info, left);

    this->node.uncompressed_base += info->uncompressed_size;
    this->node.compressed_base += info->file_size;
    this->number += info->stream_number_add;
    this->block_number_base += info->block_number_add;
    index_tree_append(info->streams, &this->node);

    if (right != NULL)
        index_cat_helper(info, right);

    return;
}
```

Errors:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'this'
>
> error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

I'm looking for the source of these errors.

Comment: I think it's a good question .. missing context. The code *is* valid C, which it looks like it was written as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compile what appears to be C code as C++. Be aware that this will introduce problems since C and C++ are distinct languages (e.g. you will have to cast the return result of `malloc`, which is discouraged in C code).

The proper thing to do would be to use a C compiler, not a C++ compiler.

Comment: But can't I use 'this' in C. I know this is not valid in C and is C++. Is there no way I can use this pointer in C code

Comment: Well, actually, `this` is perfectly valid in C as a plain identifier. In your case, you're defining a `static` function, so the C++ `this` wouldn't make sense anyway. (My point is: if you're using C, compile as C. If you compiled this code as C, it would work fine.)

Comment: Alright. Actually, the code was written to work on LINUX. But when I needed to compile it for windows, many problems arised(for instance 'bool' boolean identifier). So, I just renamed it to cpp. Most of the errors were resolved when I did this

Answer (score 6):

`this` is a [C++ keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) that you cannot use as a name for a variable. It represents a pointer to an instance of a class *from within that instance*.

Example (although `this` can actually be omitted here)

```
struct Foo
{
  void foo() const { this->bar(); }
  void bar() const {}
  void step() { this->counter++; }
  int counter = 0; // don't worry, C++11 initialization
};
```

You need a different name.

Comment: Using a different name works.Instead of 'this' used 'this_info'